# How to write regex expression to match words that start with special characters and end with a group of words

Tags: regex

I am working on the following regex problem that I have almost solved.

The goal is to find the words that start either with special characters or a space and end with one of these words including the period .qvd .txt .xlsx

For example
"list.xlsx random %ford.txt #catch.qvd cars roads"

From above string I need to extract the following
list.xlsx , ford.txt and catch.qvd

```
 [#%\S]\w+\.+txt
```

My solution only checks the words that end with .txt. How can I change my regex expression to include .qvd , and .xlsx too

Answer (score 1):

In this pattern `[#%\S]\w+\.+txt` the `\S` also matches `$` and `%` and is the same as `\S\w+\.+txt`.

That would require a string that starts with a non whitespace char and will include "special chars" in the match, and the string must be at least 2 characters long.

If there can be either a "special char" or a space or the start of the string to the left, you can start the match directly with word characters, followed by matching any of the alternatives using a non capture group `(?:txt|qvd|xlsx)` and a word boundary `\b` at the end to prevent a partial word match.

```
\w+\.(?:txt|qvd|xlsx)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aAJRks/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `|` (alternation operator/metacharacter) to express an "or" relation between two or more subexpressions:

```regex
(?<!\S)[#%]\S+\.(?:txt|qvd|xslx)
```

Comment: Thanks! What does the expression ?: mean here?

Comment: @BBB In most regex grammars `(?:...)` is a _non-capturing_ group - no different than `(...)`, except that the value matched by the subexpression `...` won't be captured separately :)